# Sudoers entry doesn't effect on script execution

Tags: dovecot, sudo

I have added entry to the sudoers to allow execute a script without typing

`jdoe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/doveadm`

but when user jdoe is trying to execute

`/usr/bin/doveadm acl get -u jdoe@testdomain.com INBOX`

it throws an error:

```
doveadm(jdoe@testdomain.com): Error: user jdoe@testdomain.com: Auth USER lookup failed
doveadm(jdoe@testdomain.com): Fatal: User lookup failed: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
```

when above request is executed with sudo

`sudo /usr/bin/doveadm acl get -u jdoe@testdomain.com INBOX`

it work fine.

Any clue what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the command `/usr/bin/doveadm` via sudo e.g.

```
sudo /usr/bin/doveadm acl get -u jdoe@testdomain.com INBOX
```

The entry in sudoers only tells sudo that the user `jdoe` is allowed to run the `/usr/bin/doveadm` command without requiring a password.

Comment: Does adding a setuid flag `chmod 4755 /usr/bin/doveadm` will solve that?

Comment: This enables _all users_ to execute dovecot management operations, I would rather not do that. If all you want to do is running multiple commands in sequence without the need of prefixing sudo all the time, consider switching to the `dovecot` user (`sudo -su dovecot` or `su - dovecot`).